# Rails 4 JSON render error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4, ancestry

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render **2.2.9 Rendering JSON** says that you can render JSON in a view as follows:

```
render json: @product
```

I can't get this to work. In index.html.erb I have:

```
render json: @trees
```

(@trees is defined as Tree.all which contains an [Ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) tree, FWIW - not relevant to the problem as far as I can tell.)

I get the following error on that line:

> You invoked render but did not give any of :partial, :template,
>   :inline, :file, :plain, :text or :body option.

I get the same error if I change that line of code to:

```
render json: {text:"hello world"}
```

What am I doing wrongly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `render` call in this form should go into the controller. If you really want to render JSON in the view, `<%= @trees.to_json %>` should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Not clear from the docs, but I see that now when rereading in light of your advice.